# SVG animation: telling a keyframe to "do nothing"

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

So I have this CSS animation:

```css
@keyframes a1 {
    25% {
        transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
        stroke: red;
    }
    50% {
        transform: translate(80px,80px) scale(1.5,1.5);
        stroke: green;
    }
    75% {
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(80px,80px) scale(1.5,1.5);
        stroke: blue;
    }
    100% {
        /* REPEATING MYSELF HERE! */
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(80px,80px) scale(1.5,1.5);
        stroke: blue;
    }
}
#r1 {
    animation-name: a1;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <title>Test Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <svg width="1000px" height="1000px">
        <rect id="r1"
              width="100" height="100" fill="transparent" stroke="black"></rect>
      </svg>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works as intended. The problem is, the **100%** keyframe is just a repeat of the **75%** keyframe, which I'd rather not do. However, if I omit anything then the attribute would reset to the beginning of the animation cycle, which is not intended.

So my question is:

- Is there a way to tell CSS to "freeze frame", so that nothing changes from the previous keyframe?
- If not, is there a more robust way than this to create the same animation?

Comment: you can do `75%,100% {}`

Comment: @TemaniAfif You mean replacing `75%` and `100%` with that? I don't know how it solves the problem. And it doesn't.

Comment: @KhoaVo - Nah, `75%, 100% {
            transform: rotate(45deg) translate(80px,80px) scale(1.5,1.5);
            stroke: blue;
        }` Instead of the 75 and 100 blocks gives the same result as your version.

Comment: @enhzflep Okay, that works. Do you want to add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @KhoaVo - you can in fact, accept your own answer to your own question! :wink:

Comment: @enhzflep Yeah, but I have to wait 2 days for that. I don't come here often so, afraid I might forget. But well I did it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was provided in the comments by @TemaniAfif and @enhzflep: I can select both keyframes as follows.

```css
75%, 100% {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(80px,80px) scale(1.5,1.5);
    stroke: blue;
}
```